# Search for color in BufferedImage Java

Tags: java, bufferedimage

I currently have a script that can create a bufferedimage of the screen, and then list the value for a specific pixel. However, I'm trying to search the entire bufferedimage for a specific color. Is there a way to do this?

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException, AWTException {
        BufferedImage image = new Robot().createScreenCapture(new Rectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize()));

        int x = 10;
        int y = 10;

        int clr = image.getRGB(x, y);
        int red = (clr & 0x00ff0000) >> 16;
        int green = (clr & 0x0000ff00) >> 8;
        int blue = clr & 0x000000ff;
        System.out.println("Red  = " + red);
        System.out.println("Green  = " + green);
        System.out.println("Blue  = " + blue);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use nested `for` loops for every (x, y) coordinate of the image (with `x` between 0 and `image.getWidth()`, and `y` between 0 and `image.getHeight()`) and compare if the color at the given position is equal to the color you are looking for.

Comment: That actually works perfectly. However, I think I need the opposite: where the script stops once a particular color is **not** in the area. My mistake.